# Parsing Function Calls with `constexpr` library in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, compiler-construction, c++17, constexpr

I'm at the end of the semester and need to get this in, I have been struggling for the last few days to implement function calls into my language. I am using the [ctpg](https://github.com/peter-winter/ctpg) library which implements a constexpr LR1 parser in C++17 so everything is compile time, this is important because the main problem is it seems no matter what I do I end up with an infinite parsing loop at compile-time (gcc tells me some constexpr thing hits the maximum depth and there is a compiler option to make it go deeper). If your not familiar with ctpg specifically but know something about compilers, I hope you can get the "jist" of this code e.g.

```
non_terminal_term< ToReduceToHere >( non_terminal_term< Some > term< Pattern >, term< Here >, term< MyRegex >, term< MyString >, term< MyChar > )
>= []( auto some, auto pattern, auto fed_here, auto my_regex, auto my_string, auto my_char ) {
    // Do something ... 
    return MyDataTypeCorrespondingTo<ToReduceToHere> {};
}

//Simple list parser using raw library.//

ctpg::nterm< std::vector< int > > list;
ctpg::regex_term< "[1-9][0-9]*" > number;

ctpg::parser list_parser(  
    list, // What to reduce too
    ctpg::terms( number, ',' ), 
    ctpg::nterms( list ), 
    ctpg::rules( 
        list( number, ',' )
        >= []( auto number, auto comma ) 
            std::vector< int > new_list;
            new_list.push_back( to_int( number ) );
            return new_list;
        }, 
        list( list, number, ',' )
        >= []( auto current_list, auto num, auto comma ) 
            current_list.push_back( to_int( num ) );
            return current_list;
        }
    )
);
```

I want functions calls to be "factors" and usable in mathematical expressions (functions are just simple arithmetic expressions in my language with, argument lists (which have comparisons and logical operators).

The way I get factors right now is something like this:

```
////////////////////////////////  "Literals" ////////////////////////////////

non_terminal_term< Factor >( term< FunctionResult > )  //`@` is a special variable used for a contracts, nothing really to do with call syntax. //
        >= []( auto token ) {
                return std::move( Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< FunctionResult >() );
        }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( term< Identifier > ) 
        >= []( auto token ) {
                return std::move( Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< 
                                Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeType::Identifier 
                        >( Warp::Utilities::hash_string( token ) ) );
        }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( term< NaturalNumber > ) 
        >= []( auto token )
        {
                return std::move( Warp::Utilities::allocate_integral_literal_node< 
                        ResolvedType< NaturalNumber > 
                    >( token ) );
        }, 
////////////////////////////////  Multiplication/Division ////////////////////////////////

non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< FactorMultiply >, term< NaturalNumber > ) 
        >= []( auto current_factor, auto, const auto& next_token )
            {
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< FactorMultiply >( 
                        current_factor, 
                        Warp::Utilities::allocate_integral_literal_node< 
                                ResolvedType< NaturalNumber > 
                            >( next_token )
                    );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< FactorDivide >, term< NaturalNumber > ) 
        >= []( auto current_factor, auto, const auto& next_token )
            {
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< FactorDivide >( 
                        current_factor, 
                        Warp::Utilities::allocate_integral_literal_node< 
                                ResolvedType< NaturalNumber > 
                            >( next_token )
                    );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< FactorMultiply >, term< Identifier > ) 
        >= []( auto current_factor, auto, const auto& next_token )
            {
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< FactorMultiply >( 
                        current_factor, 
                        Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< 
                                Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeType::Identifier 
                            >( Warp::Utilities::hash_string( next_token ) )
                    );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< FactorDivide >, term< Identifier > ) 
        >= []( auto current_factor, auto, const auto& next_token )
            {
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< FactorDivide >( 
                        current_factor, 
                        Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< 
                                Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeType::Identifier 
                            >( Warp::Utilities::hash_string( next_token ) )
                    );
            }, 

////////////////////////////////  Parenthesis ////////////////////////////////

non_terminal_term< ParenthesisScope >( term< OpenParenthesis >, non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< CloseParenthesis > )
        >= [] ( auto, auto factor, auto ) { return factor; }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< ParenthesisScope > ) 
        >= []( auto parenthesis_scope ) { return parenthesis_scope; }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< FactorMultiply >, non_terminal_term< ParenthesisScope > ) 
        >= []( auto factor, auto, auto parenthesis_scope ) 
            {
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< FactorMultiply >( 
                        factor, 
                        parenthesis_scope 
                    );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< FactorDivide >, non_terminal_term< ParenthesisScope > ) 
        >= []( auto factor, auto, auto parenthesis_scope ) 
            {
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< FactorDivide >( 
                        factor, 
                        parenthesis_scope 
                    );
            }, 
////////////////////////////////  Addition/Subtraction ////////////////////////////////
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Sum > ) 
        >= []( auto sum ) {
            return sum;
        }, 
non_terminal_term< Sum >( non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< SumAdd >, non_terminal_term< Factor > ) 
        >= []( auto current_sum, auto, const auto& next_token ) 
            {
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< SumAdd >( 
                        current_sum, 
                        next_token 
                    );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Sum >( non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< SumSubtract >, non_terminal_term< Factor > ) 
        >= []( auto current_sum, auto, const auto& next_token )
            {
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< SumSubtract >( 
                        current_sum, 
                        next_token 
                    );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Expression >( non_terminal_term< Factor > ) 
        >= []( auto factor ) {
            return factor;
        }, 
//...
```

If I am just trying to reduce factors the following works perfectly

```
non_terminal_term< Call >( term< Identifier >, term< OpenParenthesis > ) 
        >= []( auto identifier, auto ) // function, auto identifier, auto )
            {
                std::cout << "Call found!\n";
                return Warp::CompilerRuntime::CallType{ 
                        Warp::Utilities::hash_string( identifier ), 
                        Warp::Utilities::VectorType< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeVariantType >{} 
                    };
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Call >( non_terminal_term< Call >, non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< FunctionParameterNextParameter > ) 
        >= [](auto call, auto argument, auto )
            {
                std::cout << "Argument buffered!\n";
                return Warp::CompilerRuntime::CallType{ 
                        call.identifier, 
                        Warp::Utilities::VectorType< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeVariantType >{ 
                                call.arguments, 
                                argument 
                            } 
                    };
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Call >, non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< CloseParenthesis > ) 
        >= []( auto call, auto argument, auto )
            {
                std::cout << "Call end 0!\n";
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeType::FunctionCall >( 
                        call.identifier, 
                        Warp::Utilities::VectorType< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeVariantType >{ 
                                call.arguments, 
                                argument 
                            } 
                    );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Call >, term< CloseParenthesis > ) 
        >= []( auto call, auto )
            {
                std::cout << "Call end 1!\n";
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeType::FunctionCall >( 
                        call.identifier, 
                        call.arguments 
                    );
            }
```

Here are the test cases

```
static TestSuiteType factor_calls{
        WarpTest{ true, "test( 1 )" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "test( a )" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "20 * test( a )" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "20 + test( a )" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "test( a ) * 20" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "test( a ) + 10" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "test( a * a )" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "test( a(), b( q, 4, 5646, 345345 * 445656 + 34 ), rdfg * 34534 )" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "test( a, q, 4, 5646, 345345 * 445656 + 34, rdfg * 34534 )" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "test( ttt(), q, 4, 5646, 345345 * 445656 + 34, rdfg * 34534 )" } 
    };
```

But when I try to put it in the context of reducing a function the compiler seems to get into an infinite loop and wont compile the parser. To get an idea of the test cases I am working with for a whole function:

```
static TestSuiteType function_alternative_calls{
        WarpTest{ true, "let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( 1 );" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a );" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "let test( a : a < 64 ) :: 20 * test( a );" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "let test( a : a < 64 ) :: 20 + test( a );" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a ) * 20;" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a ) + 10;" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a * a );" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a(), b( q, 4, 5646, 345345 * 445656 + 34 ), rdfg * 34534 );" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a, q, 4, 5646, 345345 * 445656 + 34, rdfg * 34534 );" }, 
        WarpTest{ true, "let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( ttt(), q, 4, 5646, 345345 * 445656 + 34, rdfg * 34534 );" } 
    };
```

Its crucial I make this work so my language can be Turing complete and I can use recursion.

I am able to get all these tests with the exception of 3, here are those results:

```
Pass: let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( 1 );
Pass: let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a );
[1:36] PARSE: Syntax error: Unexpected '('
Fail: let test( a : a < 64 ) :: 20 * test( a );
[1:38] PARSE: Syntax error: Unexpected 'Identifier'
Fail: let test( a : a < 64 ) :: 20 + test( a );
Pass: let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a ) * 20;
[1:37] PARSE: Syntax error: Unexpected '+'
Fail: let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a ) + 10;
Pass: let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a * a );
Pass: let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a(), b( q, 4, 5646, 345345 * 445656 + 34 ), rdfg * 34534 );
Pass: let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( a, q, 4, 5646, 345345 * 445656 + 34, rdfg * 34534 );
Pass: let test( a : a < 64 ) :: test( ttt(), q, 4, 5646, 345345 * 445656 + 34, rdfg * 34534 );
```

Here is the code that makes that work:

```
//... code that analyzes function parameters tries to buffer the expression after the `::` operator
non_terminal_term< ExpressionEater >( non_terminal_term< ExpressionEater >, term< FactorMultiply >, non_terminal_term< Expression > ) 
        >= []( auto function, auto, auto factor ) {
                return subsume_function_alternative_expression< FactorMultiply >( function, factor );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< ExpressionEater >( non_terminal_term< ExpressionEater >, term< FactorDivide >, non_terminal_term< Expression > ) 
        >= []( auto function, auto, auto factor ) {
                return subsume_function_alternative_expression< FactorDivide >( function, factor );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Call >( term< Identifier >, term< OpenParenthesis > ) 
        >= []( auto identifier, auto ) 
            {
                return Warp::CompilerRuntime::CallType{ 
                        Warp::Utilities::hash_string( identifier ), 
                        std::vector< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeVariantType >{}
                        //Warp::Utilities::VectorType< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeVariantType >{} 
                    };
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Call >( non_terminal_term< Call >, non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< FunctionParameterNextParameter > ) 
        >= [](auto call, auto argument, auto ) {
                call.arguments.push_back( argument );
                return call;
            }, 
non_terminal_term< CallNode >( non_terminal_term< Call >, non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< CloseParenthesis > ) 
        >= []( auto call, auto argument, auto )
            {
                call.arguments.push_back( argument );
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeType::FunctionCall >( 
                        call.identifier, 
                        call.arguments 
                    );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Call >( non_terminal_term< Call >, non_terminal_term< CallNode >, term< FunctionParameterNextParameter > ) 
        >= [](auto call, auto argument, auto ) {
                call.arguments.push_back( argument );
                return call;
            }, 
non_terminal_term< CallNode >( non_terminal_term< Call >, non_terminal_term< CallNode >, term< CloseParenthesis > ) 
        >= []( auto call, auto argument, auto )
            {
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeType::FunctionCall >( 
                        call.identifier, 
                        call.arguments 
                    );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< CallNode >( non_terminal_term< Call >, term< CloseParenthesis > ) 
        >= []( auto call, auto )
            {
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeType::FunctionCall >( 
                        call.identifier, 
                        call.arguments 
                    );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Expression >( non_terminal_term< CallNode > )
        >= []( auto call ) {
                return call;
            }
```

As you may be able to see this is a bit of a "hack" partially re-implementing factors towards the top there.
It cant do sums and it cant take into account any products before the function call.

I have tried everything you can see some of the changes I have made in detail [on this branch](https://github.com/cgbsu/WarpBootstrapCompiler0/commits/lets_make_it_work) but to summarize, the main problem is though if I try to make this "complete" in any sense where it loops back to a factor or its equivalent and treats the call like a factor (as I want it too) the compiler infinitely loops, even though it works just fine when reducing just a factor. It doesent seem to matter where I put the terminal terms, non-terminal-terms, etc.

One thing I have also tried is never "leaving" factor evaluation.

```
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< FactorMultiply >, term< Identifier >, term< OpenParenthesis > ) 
        >= []( auto factor, auto, auto identifier, auto ) 
            {
                return Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< FactorMultiply >( 
                        factor, 
                        Warp::Utilities::allocate_node< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeType::FunctionCall >( 
                                Warp::Utilities::hash_string( identifier ), 
                                std::vector< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeVariantType >{} 
                                // Warp::Utilities::VectorType< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeVariantType >{} 
                            ) 
                    );
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Factor >, non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< FunctionParameterNextParameter > ) 
        >= []( auto operation_call, auto argument, auto )
            {
                if( Warp::Utilities::is_bi_node( operation_call ) == false ) 
                {
                    std::cerr << "ERROR!!!: Attempt to parse function call failed! "
                            << "Bi-Node not found where expected (Factor, Factor, NextParmaeterToken(Comma))! "
                            << "Returning first factor.\n";
                }
                auto proxy = Warp::Utilities::bi_node_proxy( operation_call ).value();
                if( Warp::Utilities::tag_is< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeType::FunctionCall >( proxy.right ) == true )
                {
                    std::cerr << "ERROR!!!: Attempt to parse function call failed! "
                            << "FunctionCall not found where expected (Factor (left: Factor, right: FunctionCall), "
                            << "Factor, NextParmaeterToken(Comma))! Returning first factor.\n";
                }
                auto call = static_cast< Warp::CompilerRuntime::CallType* >( proxy.right->get_data() );
                call->arguments.push_back( argument );
                return operation_call;
            }, 
non_terminal_term< Factor >( non_terminal_term< Factor >, non_terminal_term< Factor >, term< CloseParenthesis > ) 
        >= []( auto operation_call, auto argument, auto )
            {
                if( Warp::Utilities::is_bi_node( operation_call ) == false ) 
                {
                    std::cerr << "ERROR!!!: Attempt to parse function call failed! "
                            << "Bi-Node not found where expected (Factor, Factor, CloseParenthesis)! "
                            << "Returning first factor.\n";
                }
                auto proxy = Warp::Utilities::bi_node_proxy( operation_call ).value();
                if( Warp::Utilities::tag_is< Warp::AbstractSyntaxTree::NodeType::FunctionCall >( proxy.right ) == true )
                {
                    std::cerr << "ERROR!!!: Attempt to parse function call failed! "
                            << "FunctionCall not found where expected (Factor (left: Factor, right: FunctionCall), "
                            << "Factor, CloseParenthesis)! Returning first factor.\n";
                }
                auto call = static_cast< Warp::CompilerRuntime::CallType* >( proxy.right->get_data() );
                call->arguments.push_back( argument );
                return operation_call;
            }
```

Unfortunately its the same result :(

An attempt at some pseudo - BNF's I have tried

```
call := 
            | <identifier > (
            | <call> <factor> , 
            | <complete-call> , 
complete-call = 
            | <call> < factor > )
            | <call> )
factor/expression = complete-call
```

```
call := 
            | <identifier > (
            | <call> <argument-list> )
            | <call> )
argument-list = 
            | <factor> ,
            | <argument-list> <factor>,
```

```
factor := 
            | <factor> * <literal>
            | <factor> / <literal>
            | <factor> * <identifier> (
            | <factor>, 
            | <factor> )
```

All these in various permutations and versions (again you can look at my changes [on this branch](https://github.com/cgbsu/WarpBootstrapCompiler0/commits/lets_make_it_work)

How do I make this terminal so the compiler does not churn forever and I can parse function calls?

I'm really under the wire, any help would really be appreciated!

Thank you so much for reading!

Comment: First of all, have you tried increasing the max `constexpr` recursion depth and number of instructions? It would not surprise me if the defaults are too small for such a complex task.

Comment: @user17732522
Thanks for the response! I have not, I will give it a try on a few of my implementations, it seems pretty high though `33554432`

Comment: The function call depth default is "only" 512, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html (There are more relevant options.)

Comment: `-fconstexpr-ops-limit=3355443299`
Well it compiles now  I guess I should not have assumed it was already high enough and in an infinite loop.

Thank you both!!

Comment: It works now, @user17732522 post as answer and I will mark it as  such since you answered first. Thank you so much!!!!! :D